# Const expressions in C - How to hash a string?

Tags: c, hash, constexpr

I am creating a kernel module. In this module I need to check inputs against some pre-defined strings.
In C++ it's possible to create a constexpr function that calculates the hash at compile time. I am looking for a way to do that in C.

Some pseudo code using [the Jenkins hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenkins_hash_function):

```
u32 hash(const char *key)
{
    u32 hash, i;
    size_t len;

    len = strlen(key);
    for(hash = i = 0; i < len; ++i)
    {
        hash += key[i];
        hash += (hash << 10);
        hash ^= (hash >> 6);
    }
    hash += (hash << 3);
    hash ^= (hash >> 11);
    hash += (hash << 15);
    return hash;
}


const u32 myStringList [] = {
    hash("hello"),
    hash("this is a text"),
    hash("good morning")
};

int findString(const char * searchStr) {
    u32 h;
    int i;

    h = hash(searchStr);
    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(myStringList)/sizeof(const u32); i++) {
        if (h == myStringList[i]) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

How to modify it to get work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you can, C doesn't have `constexpr` or compile-time evaluation. That's why many people turn to the preprocessor (which is less often used in C++), but string processing (as opposed to string "construction") using that isn't very easy.

Sometimes this can be worked around by adding another preprocessing step, perhaps using some higher-level language (I favor Python) to build the required C code.

If that's not an option, then I'd simply initialize the hash table once during startup. If you don't have an explicit init-function (I believe Linux kernel modules do), you can of course use a static flag:

```
static const char *strings[] = { "hello", "this is a text", "good morning", NULL };
static uint32_t myStringList[(sizeof strings / sizeof *strings) - 1];

void something(const char *string)
{
  static bool hash_initialized = false;
  if(!hash_initialized)
  {
    for(size_t i = 0; strings[i] != NULL; ++i)
      myStringList[i] = hash(strings[i]);
    hash_initialized = true;
  }
  if(hash_lookup(string))
  {
   ...
  }
}
```